# How can I use the root password provided by the user in my bash installation script

Tags: bash, passwords, command, sudo, kdialog

I'm trying to install a cronjob to run a bash shell script on a relative's machine. They will run the install and I can't access it remotely yet (that's what my script is for - but that's not the issue here). I use kdialog to request their root password and then want to use that to sudo various commands. My code below is failing by a) revealing the root p/w on the terminal and b) failing to pipe it to the various sudos. Help?

```
#!/bin/bash
kdialog --password "Please enter your root password to install theCronScript.sh and set up cron"

# Sanity checks =========================================╕
if test -z "$BASH" ; then
        printf "$SCRIPT:$LINENO: please run this script with the BASH shell\n">&2
        exit 192
fi
#========================================================╛

# Global variables=======================================╕
PW="$?"
THISDIR="$(pwd)"
GETIPFILE='theCronScript.sh'
CRONPERIOD='/15 *   *   *   *   '
TARGETCRONDIR='/etc/cron.hourly'
#========================================================╛
echo "hi"

# txt file exists check =================================╕
echo "Checking:"
if [ ! -f "$THISDIR/$GETIPFILE" ]; then #there's no file to install
  kdialog --msgbox "I cannot find $GETIPFILE to upload\nPlease check attachments in recent e-mails from Greg and download $GETIPFILE to $THISDIR"
  exit
else
  if [ -f "$TARGETCRONDIR/$GETIPFILE" ]; then #the target already exists
    kdialog --title "Replace or Keep" --warningyesno "A similar file already exists.\n Do you want to replace it (recommended)?\n(The original file will be saved with a different name _OLD)"
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then # rename, then replace the existing file
      #echo $PW is probably unneccessary beyond the first use but just in case...
      RNGETIPFILE=$GETIPFILE'_OLD'
      echo $PW | sudo -S mv $TARGETCRONDIR/$GETIPFILE $TARGETCRONDIR/$RNGETIPFILE #rename original file
      echo $PW | sudo -S cp $THISDIR/$GETIPFILE $TARGETCRONDIR/$GETIPFILE #copy new version in
      echo $PW | sudo -S chmod +x $TARGETCRONDIR/$GETIPFILE #
      echo $PW | sudo -S crontab -l > mycron #write out current crontab
      echo $PW | sudo -S echo $CRONPERIOD   $TARGETCRONDIR >> mycron #echo new cron into cron file
      echo $PW | sudo -S crontab mycron  #install new cron file
      rm mycron
      $PW="" #clear password variable once it's no longer required
    else # Don't replace, exit
      exit
    fi
  else # Nothing to replace. Just copy it in
      echo $PW | sudo -S "cp $THISDIR/$GETIPFILE $TARGETCRONDIR/$GETIPFILE" #copy new version in
      echo $PW | sudo -S chmod +x $TARGETCRONDIR/$GETIPFILE # make sure it's executable
      echo $PW | sudo -S crontab -l > mycron #write out current crontab
      echo $PW | sudo -S echo $CRONPERIOD   $TARGETCRONDIR >> mycron  #echo new cron into cron file
      echo $PW | sudo -S crontab mycron #install new cron file
      rm mycron
      $PW="" #clear password variable once it's no longer required
  fi
fi

exit 0
#========================================================╛
```

Comment: Why don't you simply instruct them to run the script with `sudo`?

Comment: As the simplest (though less appealing) solution, I may do that and make the script interactive on the terminal. Given time and more skills, zeroconf's would be my preferred route. I'm just wary of having to add another shell script (to wrapper the external kdialog command).

Comment: You can always just use `ssh-askpass`, which will work just fine, but it will look like it's asking for an ssh password. You can also have your script actually just create the `kdialog` wrapper script before running it (no additional files necessary). Let me know if you want an example.

Comment: Yes please - code snippet or link to one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to ask for the password directly in the `sudo` command via an external GUI. From the `sudo` manpage:

```
 -A, --askpass
             Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's terminal.  If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical)
             helper program is executed to read the user's password and output the password to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable is
             set, it specifies the path to the helper program.  Otherwise, if sudo.conf(5) contains a line specifying the askpass program, that value will be
             used.  For example:

                 # Path to askpass helper program
                 Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass

             If no askpass program is available, sudo will exit with an error.
```

if `sudo` is caching credentials, it will only ask for this password once. One way I use to get this cached would be, having no side effects other than caching the password:

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass
sudo --askpass true
```

Depending on what distro you're running, `ssh-askpass` may be somewhere else. There is an [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81181/86056) on StackExchange on how you might use `kdialog` to get the password for the `sudo` askpass. For reference, here is the script:

```
$ cat myaskpass.sh 
#!/bin/bash
kdialog --password "Please enter your password: "
exit 0
```

And how you would use it:

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/path/to/myaskpass.sh
sudo --askpass true
```